# How do I get ubuntu to stay installed?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying out Ubuntu, I have installed it numerous times only to have it ask me to either try ubuntu or install it.It will not take the installment. It seems to work in trial mode but  if installed after rebooting I am asked again to install it.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? In the trial mode it works just fine most of the time. It sometimes locks up and I have to then reinstall ubuntu in trial mode. It is a pain as I lose what I have installed.

My computer is an older model that had Windows XP Pro 32 bit on it. XP Pro has been removed and the 1 TB HD re-formated so there is no trace of Xp Pro. Only ubuntu is on my HD.
I would like to have both ubuntu and Win XP installed but it is not possible at this point.

Comment: After you have installed it, you can take the disk or whatever you installed it from, and you should be able to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you removed the installation media after you have installed it?

Comment: I have taken out the installation disk  after I installed the latest ubuntu and rebooted as requested. It does not seem to matter. It will not install. All I can do is run the trial version of ubuntu. I have removed all cds and usb drives. No dice. I would like to use ubuntu but at this point I am going to have to install Windows 7 instead. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Curious, did you install from the first menu where it offers 2 choices try or install. Or did you install from within the live trial desktop?

Answer (score 2):

After the installation, remove the installation media (USB stick, CD, DVD) that you used for installation.

Comment: I have removed the installation media and removed any extra usb drives I have installed. It does not matter. Each time I  reboot it asks if I want to run or install ubuntu. Thanx for the help.

Comment: @user248659, if you really have removed the installation media, then there is nothing there to offer to install, so you must not have.

Comment: @user248659 so what do you mean by "you are asked again to install it"? The ubuntu installer actually shows up, *without* the install media being present?